# How could I convert tensor type to numpy narray type in my function?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, tensor

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data


def weight_variable(shape):
    initial = tf.truncated_normal(shape, stddev=0.1)
    return tf.Variable(initial)


def bias_variable(shape):
    initial = tf.constant(0.1, shape=shape)
    return tf.Variable(initial)
```

> ```
> def conv2d(x, w):
>     x_narray = something operate on x
>     w_narray = something operate on w
>     result = my_conv_function(x_narray, w_narray, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')
>     return result
> ```

```
def max_pool_2_2(x):
    return tf.nn.max_pool(x, ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1], strides=[1, 2, 2, 1],    padding='SAME')


mnist = input_data.read_data_sets('MNIST_data', one_hot=True)

x = tf.placeholder("float", shape=[None, 784])
y_ = tf.placeholder("float", shape=[None, 10])
x_image = tf.reshape(x, [-1, 28, 28, 1])

w_conv1 = weight_variable([5, 5, 1, 32])
b_conv1 = bias_variable([32])
h_conv1 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(x_image, w_conv1) + b_conv1)
h_pool1 = max_pool_2_2(h_conv1)

w_conv2 = weight_variable([5, 5, 32, 64])
b_conv2 = bias_variable([64])
h_conv2 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(h_pool1, w_conv2) + b_conv2)
h_pool2 = max_pool_2_2(h_conv2)

w_fc1 = weight_variable([7 * 7 * 64, 1024])
b_fc1 = bias_variable([1024])
h_pool2_flat = tf.reshape(h_pool2, [-1, 7 * 7 * 64])
h_fc1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(h_pool2_flat, w_fc1) + b_fc1)

keep_prob = tf.placeholder("float")
h_fc1_drop = tf.nn.dropout(h_fc1, keep_prob)

w_fc2 = weight_variable([1024, 10])
b_fc2 = bias_variable([10])

y_conv = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(h_fc1_drop, w_fc2) + b_fc2)

cross_entropy = -tf.reduce_sum(y_ * tf.log(y_conv))
train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(1e-4).minimize(cross_entropy)
correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y_conv, 1), tf.argmax(y_, 1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, "float"))

sess = tf.Session()
with sess.as_default():
    sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
    for i in range(10000):
        batch = mnist.train.next_batch(50)
        if i % 100 == 0:
            train_accuracy = accuracy.eval(feed_dict={x: batch[0], y_: batch[1], keep_prob: 1.0})
            print("step %d, train_accuracy %g" % (i, train_accuracy))
            train_step.run(feed_dict={x: batch[0], y_: batch[1], keep_prob: 0.5})
    print("test accuracy %g" % accuracy.eval(feed_dict={x: mnist.test.images, y_: mnist.test.labels, keep_prob: 1.0}))
```

In my code, I implement a function called my_conv_function() to replace the tf.nn.conv2d function. My function need numpy.narray type parameters, but the x and y are all tensor type in tensorflow. How could I convert them to numpy.narray type?

Comment: Did you try array = yourTensor.eval(session=yourSession) ?

Comment: def conv2d(x, w):
            print(w.eval(session=sess))
            result = tf.nn.conv2d(x, w, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')
            return result      /////could this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sess.run([yourTensor])` or `yourTensor.eval()` should return a numpy array that you need. I might be wrong, but I was under the impression that doing that too many times slows things down though, as essentially you have to run the graph every time?

Comment: Do you have some advises to implement my idea? I want to use my function  which is wrote by python to replace the tensorflow function, but I also need tensorflow functions to deal with my function's result. How could I make them work together well? I am a new user of tensorflow.

Comment: The proper way is to [write an extension for TensorFlow](https://www.tensorflow.org/extend/adding_an_op) that actually uses tensors. If you have to evaluate tensors dynamically it will get slow eventually.

Comment: Thanks for your advise! Maybe I should do this.